# Running Java application on server

Tags: java

I have access to a server using SSH. I need to run a stand-alone Java application on it to access a MySQL server installed there. How do I go about in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the requirement to copy the JAR file on the *nix box and then run it(and not connect a Java process to it remotely)

- Create a standalone JAR which contains all the dependencies required to run the application
- Make sure you have Java installed on that machine
- Assuming it's a *nix box, set the $PATH environment variable to point to $JAVA_HOME/bin
- Log on to that box using a SSH client. Any decent SSH client also comes with a FTP plugin which allows you to transfer files between your local box and the server
- Copy the JAR to the appropriate directory and run it using the `java -jar your.jar` command

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is a linux machine, you have to connect to by using `SSH` it and use `scp` command to upload the files and deploy it...
than you have to run the JAR you deployed:

`java -jar /path/to/file.jar`

Or, provide more details please